# getting Cygwin to know about microsoft cl and nmake?

Tags: visual-c++, fortran, cygwin, fortran77, nmake

I am trying to compile the Fortran runtime library (`f2c`) in Cygwin using this command: `nmake -f makefile.vc all`
Per instruction given in the package, first I have to let Cygwin know about Microsoft `cl` compiler and `nmake`. How can I do this in Cygwin? 
I already added `vcvarsall.bat` to the `Cygwin.bat` file but I don't know what I can do for `nmake`. At this moment, I get this error: `-bash nmake: command not found`

Comment: Always use tag [tag:fortran] and only add the version when necessary to distinguish that your question is specific. For example that you cannot use Fortran 2008 but only Fortran 90.

Answer (score 4):

`nmake` executable path should be present in your `$PATH` environment variable. You should edit .bashrc file to achieve this. It could be found here: `/home/user/.bashrc` Or if you prefer a windows editor then: `c:\cygwin\home\user\.bashrc`

Add this line with the correct path to the end of the file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files/path_to_dir_which_contains_nmake.exe"
```

After that a new cygwin terminal should be started, in which you can use `nmake` command.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I added the nmake path to the file you mentioned as `export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin/nmake.exe"` to the end of `.bashrc` file. Then I opened a new Cygwin terminal but still I get the same error. I have `nmake.exe`in the folder mentioned.

Comment: @user3439894: I changed the `$PATH` to `export PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/'Program Files (x86)'/'Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0'/VC/bin/nmake.exe"` but still does not work (saying `-bash: nmake: command not found`). I also tried the other way you mentioned, but it did not work.

Comment: @user3439894: Yes, I tried in that form with backslashes too. Unfortunately, it did not work.

Comment: @user3439894: Thanks, I appreciate your help. Hope someone else can help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Spaces should not be escaped in this case. I've tried it just now.
Actually the problem is that you added the path to `nmake.exe`, and not the container directory. So you should add this line:
`PATH="$PATH:/cygdrive/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0/VC/bin"`