# How to make a user dissector in wireshark?

Tags: cygwin, wireshark

I am using window 8, 64-bit.
I follow the steps from [wireshark tutorial](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsdg_html_chunked/ChDissectAdd.html). I download files from [code project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19426/Creating-Your-Own-Custom-Wireshark-Dissector). I have installed cygwin but when I try `nmake Makefile.nmake`, I get `-bash: nmake: command not found`.

How to solve this problem?
I also found [this](https://superuser.com/questions/146577/where-do-i-find-nmake-for-windows-7), I have already installed Visual Studio 2013, should I have the nmake also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You surely don't have `nmake` on your computer. Open the Cygwin's setup.exe, follow the steps, then you'll be face to face with a list, type `nmake` in the search field and DL it.

**EDIT**: As said in the comments, add the `nmake` (located in your visual studio directory) path to your environment variable PATH, and beware of spaces for directories like `Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Found something ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28310268/getting-cygwin-to-know-about-microsoft-cl-and-nmake)).
As said, you have to add the path to `nmake` (from your Visual Studio 2013) in your environment variable PATH. i.e.: `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/nmake`. Beware of space for the path to nmake, use backslashes before them.

Comment: I copy the nmake.exe and use it and it works. Thank you.